# How to load XML file from external domain using Phonegap without a proxy

Tags: cordova

The $.ajax function works on my development system, but not when loaded to the ios device. I also added an 'access' entry for the external domain in the config.xml file.

The data I need to load is an XML file not json or I would use the json load option.

I'm using this code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://external-domain.com/data.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: parseXML,
error: ajaxError

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this does actually work. No help needed.